# OpenCage Geocoder get destination and origin Line markers

Tags: geocoder

Is it possible to get a route like between origin and destination using the opencage API like the way GoogleMaps provides a route using origin and destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the OpenCage doc at https://opencagedata.com/api shows that the only functions the API supports are "reverse (lat/long to text) and forward (text to lat/long) geocoding via a RESTful API." It doesn't create routes. For that you'll need a mapping API like those from Google, Microsoft/Bing, MapQuest, etc. It appears that Open Route Service is an open source alternative. Others will know more than me.